# Group By and ILOC Errors

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error when trying to groupby and sum by dataframe by specific columns.

```
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

I've checked other solutions and it's not a double column name header issue.

See df3 below which I want to group by on all columns except last two, I want to `sum()`

dfs head shows that if I just group by the columns names it works fine but not with iloc which I know to be the correct formula to pull back column I want to group by.

I need to use ILOC as final dataframe will have many more columns.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.iloc[:,0:3]` returns a **dataframe**. So you are trying to group dataframe with another dataframe.

But you just need a column list.

can you try this:

```
dfs = df3.groupby(list(df3.iloc[:,0:3].columns))['Churn_Alive_1','Churn_Alive_0'].sum()
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I've spent so long trying to figure this out, and what you answered make immediate sense and gives me what i need. Thank you.